# kubernetes volumes not visible

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I have pod definition file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-docker-soc
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu-docker-soc
    image: rajendarre/ubuntu-docker
    command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"

  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

I have created pod successfully ,
but command `kubectl get pv` is not showing any volumes ,
as I have volume  dockersoc , it should come as volume .
please let me know understanding is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PersistentVolume is a `provisioned` cluster resource, where else local file or directory  that you mount from the underlying node directly in your pod is not a cluster resource that requires provisioning. Therefore in your example, `kubectl get pv` will not get you anything.

Here's a good [discussion](https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/persistent-volumes-pv-and-claims-pvc-in-kubernetes-bd76923a61f6) about PV/PVC on major cloud providers.